# How to accept alert message with just javascript in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am attempting to click Ok on an alert that pops up. I have attempted to do this with Selenium WebDriver and it failed. This is what I was trying in Selenium.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

I am wondering if I can attempt to accept the alert message with just java script.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and code trials the [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) [**`alertIsPresent()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent--) returns the **alert**. So one the *alert* is returned you can straightly invoke the `accept()` method as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
//or
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).dismiss();
```